# having all my scores and names in one big array

Tags: python, arrays

```
classes = input ("what class are you in ? class1, class2 or class 3? ")
if classes == ("class1"):
students = input (str("how many students are in your class "))
while int(students)>int(student):
name = input ("what is your name ")
score = input ("what is your score ")
student = student + 1
name_arr = [] 
name_arr.append(name)
name_arr.append(score)
print(name_arr)



elif classes == ("class2"):
students = input (str("how many students are in your class "))
while int(students)>int(student):
    student = student + 1
    name1 = input ("what is your name ")
    score1 = input ("what is your score ")
     name_arr = [] 
    name_arr.append(name)
    name_arr.append(score)
    print(name_arr)

    elif classes == ("class3"):
students = input (str("how many students are in your class "))
while int(students)>int(student):
    student = student + 1
    name2 = input ("what is your name ")
    score2 = input ("what is your score ")
     name_arr = [] 
    name_arr.append(name)
    name_arr.append(score)
    print(name_arr)
```

when i run the code the name and score gets printited one by one instead of one big array![enter image description here][1]

i need to have all the names and all the scores in one big array instead of having an array on by one

Comment: Please fix your code indentation

Comment: Also in python they are `list`s not arrays.  And in this instance you would most likely be better off using a `dict`

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize your array outside of your loop:

```
name_arr = [] 
while int(students)>int(student):
    name = input ("what is your name ")
    score = input ("what is your score ")
    student = student + 1

    name_arr.append(name)
    name_arr.append(score)
    print(name_arr)
```

Otherwise you just set it back to an empty list every loop.

Comment: but it says the elif is invalid

Comment: @Ben In your code, there seems to be an extra `elif`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you

```
classes = input ("what class are you in ? class1, class2 or class 3? ")
MAIN = []
if classes == "class1":
    students = input (str("how many students are in your class "))
    student=0
    while int(students)>int(student):
        name = input ("what is your name ")
        score = input ("what is your score ")
        student = student + 1
        MAIN.append(name)
        MAIN.append(score)

elif classes == "class2":
    students = input (str("how many students are in your class "))
    student=0
    while int(students)>int(student):
        student = student + 1
        name1 = input ("what is your name ")
        score1 = input ("what is your score ")
        MAIN.append(name1)
        MAIN.append(score1)

elif classes == ("class3"):
    student=0
    students = input (str("how many students are in your class "))
    while int(students)>int(student):
        student = student + 1
        name2 = input ("what is your name ")
        score2 = input ("what is your score ")
        MAIN.append(name2)
        MAIN.append(score2)
```

Comment: it doesnt print the array as one big one

Comment: @BenGeorge, now it will in (MAIN) list